# Integer translates of a scaling function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I think this is asked as a standard exercise in books about wavelets (e.g. exercise 7.2 in [Mallat's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=hbVOfWQNtB8C&pg=370)), but I couldn't find a proof.  Let $\phi$ be a scaling function (see definition below).  I would like to learn why 
$$\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} \phi(x-k) = 1 $$
almost everywhere.

**Definition.** A sequence of subspaces $\{V_j: j\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ of $L^2(\mathbb R)$ is
called a *multiresolution analysis*  if it satisfies the following:

- $V_j \subset V_{j+1}$
- $\bigcap_{j}V_j = \{0\}$
- $\overline{\bigcup_jV_j} = L^2(\mathbb R)$
- $f(x)\in V_j$ if and only if $f(2x) \in V_{j+1}$
- There exists a function $\phi \in V_0$ such that
  $\{\phi(x-k)\}_{k\in\mathbb Z}$ is an orthogonal basis for $V_0$

The function $\phi$ here is called as a *scaling function*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find the proof for this in Mallat 1989, 'Multiresolution approximations and wavelet orthonormal bases of L^2'. Theorem 1 (in particular Equations (23), (36)) is what you are after. It is not trivial, longer to prove than I immediately thought. Perhaps there is a very fast proof but I can't think of it now.

Comment: @Glen: But $1\notin L^2$. If it were, a formal argument would be $1 = \sum c_k \phi(x-k)$, and $c_k = \int 1\cdot \phi(x-k) = $const. Some tricks are required to make it rigorous.  This is not homework, you may give an outline if you have an idea.

Comment: @AgCl: What was in my mind when I wrote that was possibly using a sequence of scaled characteristic functions on longer and longer intervals, something like f_l = 2^-l\chi_{[-l,l]}.

But now I think about it some more, this doesn't seem to work.  I think I should just delete my answer until I think of a better idea, yes?

Comment: @AgCl: OK.  I just looked it up in a paper, Mallat 1989, 'Multiresolution approximations and wavelet orthonormal bases of L^2'.  Theorem 1 (in particular Equations (23), (36)) is, I think, what you are after.  It is far from immediate, longer to prove than I immediately thought.  Perhaps there is a very fast proof but I can't think of it now. I could reproduce the proof there if you wish, although it would probably be better to just read the paper.

Comment: @Glen: Thanks for the reference, that seems to be what I was looking for! Could you edit your answer with a reference to this paper, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @AgCl: No worries, edited.

Comment: [For lazy people like me...](http://www.ams.org/tran/1989-315-01/S0002-9947-1989-1008470-5/S0002-9947-1989-1008470-5.pdf)